# Google Charts QR Code generator dropping off extra parameters

Tags: qr-code

> **Warning:**  sharing your TOTP seed with third-parties breaks the very basic assumption of multi-factor authentication that the TOTP
>   seed is *secret*.

I'm generating a QR code using google charts api like this:

`https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/Example:username?secret=IISUQVZSJ4XWSQBS&issuer=Example`

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/Example:username?secret=IISUQVZSJ4XWSQBS&issuer=Example

Here it is so you can click on the link

I'm using https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx to decode the qr

But it seems the code keeps getting generated without the

`&issuer=Example` part

I've tried encoding / decoding the uri but nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

You should try to encode the ampersand:

[https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/Example:username?secret=IISUQVZSJ4XWSQBS%26issuer=Example](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/Example:username?secret=IISUQVZSJ4XWSQBS%26issuer=Example)